# How to merge database query results using Vertx SQL interface

Tags: java, asynchronous, nonblocking, vert.x

I would like to use [Vertx common SQL Interface](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-sql-common/java/) to query from table `t1`, `t2`, `t3` in database `TDB` and together with table `s1`, `s2`, `s3` from database `SDB` and return them as a `JsonObject`. The final result should be like this

```
{
    "t1": [{...},{...},...],
    "t2": [{...},{...},...],
    "t3": [{...},{...},...],
    "s1": [{...},{...},...],
    "s2": [{...},{...},...],
    "s3": [{...},{...},...]
}
```

If it were to be only one table, I would do it like this

```
JDBCClient tdbClient = JDBCClient.createShared(vertx, tdbConfig, "TDB");
JDBCClient sdbClient = JDBCClient.createShared(vertx, sdbConfig, "SDB");
vertx.eventBus().consumer("myservice.getdata").handler(msg -> {
    tdbClient.getConnection(tConresult -> { 
        if (tConresult.succeeded()) {
            SQLConnection tConnection = tConresult.result();
            tConnection.query("select * from t1", t1 -> { 
                if (t1.succeeded()) {
                    JsonArray t1Result = new JsonArray(t1.result().getRows());
                    JsonObject allResult = new JsonObject()
                        .put("t1", t1Result);
                    msg.reply(allResult);
                } else {
                    msg.fail(1, "failt to query t1");
                }
            });
        } else {
            msg.fail(1, "connot get connection to TDB");
        }
    });
});
```

But since it have to be many tables, I find an ugly way like this

```
vertx.eventBus().consumer("myservice.getdata").handler(msg -> {
    tdbClient.getConnection(tConresult -> { if (tConresult.succeeded()) {
    sdbClient.getConnection(sConresult -> { if (sConresult.succeeded()) {
    SQLConnection tConnection = tConresult.result();
    SQLConnection sConnection = sConresult.result();
        tConnection.query("select * from t1", t1 -> { if (t1.succeeded()) {
        tConnection.query("select * from t2", t2 -> { if (t2.succeeded()) {
        tConnection.query("select * from t3", t3 -> { if (t3.succeeded()) {
        sConnection.query("select * from s1", s1 -> { if (s1.succeeded()) {
        sConnection.query("select * from s2", s2 -> { if (s2.succeeded()) {
        sConnection.query("select * from s3", s3 -> { if (s3.succeeded()) {
            JsonArray t1Result = new JsonArray(t1.result().getRows());
            JsonArray t2Result = new JsonArray(t2.result().getRows());
            JsonArray t3Result = new JsonArray(t3.result().getRows());
            JsonArray s1Result = new JsonArray(s1.result().getRows());
            JsonArray s2Result = new JsonArray(s2.result().getRows());
            JsonArray s3Result = new JsonArray(s3.result().getRows());
            JsonObject allResult = new JsonObject()
                .put("t1", t1Result)
                .put("t2", t2Result)
                .put("t3", t3Result)
                .put("s1", s1Result)
                .put("s2", s2Result)
                .put("s3", s3Result);
            msg.reply(allResult);
        } else {msg.fail(1, "failt to query s3");}});
        } else {msg.fail(1, "failt to query s2");}});
        } else {msg.fail(1, "failt to query s1");}});
        } else {msg.fail(1, "failt to query t3");}});
        } else {msg.fail(1, "failt to query t2");}});
        } else {msg.fail(1, "failt to query t1");}});
    } else {msg.fail(1, "connot get connection to SDB");}});
    } else {msg.fail(1, "connot get connection to TDB");}});
});
```

But I think I'm doing it wrong, despite of the ugly code, it takes a lot of time to process because it doesn't do the queries in parallel.

Please suggest a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are experiencing here is the [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/). Vert.x provides some features to handle `AsyncResult` in a much more composable and convient way than callbacks. They are called `Future`. I suggest you read about them in the [documentation](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_async_coordination).
A `Future` is a placeholder for results of asynchronous calls. Vert.x is full of asynchronous calls. If asynchronous calls depend on each other you typically end up with a callback hell. With `Future` you can do something like this:

```
Future<SQLConnection> tConResultFuture = Future.future();
tdbClient.getConnection(tConresult -> {
  if (tConresult.succeeded()) {
    logger.info("Yeah got a connection! tCon");
    tConResultFuture.complete(tConresult.result());
  } else {
    tConResultFuture.fail(tConresult.cause());
  }
});
```

The `Handler` for the `AsyncResult<SQLConnection>` put the asynchronous result of getting a `SQLConnection` into the `Future tConResultFuture`. Now you can a `Handler` for the `Future` and wait for the asynchronous result for `getConnection`:

```
tConResultFuture.setHandler(result -> {
  // ...
});
```

But that wouldn't make much sense as you already could to that with the first `Handler`. Now think of an example like yours – with many depending `Futures`. I use your example add a second connection – the `sConresult`:

```
Future<SQLConnection> sConResultFuture = Future.future();
sdbClient.getConnection(sConresult -> {
  if (sConresult.succeeded()) {
    logger.info("Yeah got a connection! sCon");
    sConResultFuture.complete(sConresult.result());
  } else {
    sConResultFuture.fail(sConresult.cause());
  }
});
```

So lets say, you want to wait for both `Future` results because they depend on each other. Here we use Vert.x' `CompositeFuture`:

```
CompositeFuture.all(tConResultFuture, sConResultFuture).setHandler(connections -> {
  if (connections.succeeded()) {
    logger.info("Both connections are ready for use!");

    SQLConnection tCon = tConResultFuture.result();
    SQLConnection sCon = sConResultFuture.result();

    // do stuff...
  } else {
    logger.severe("Both or one connections attempt failed!");
  }
});
```

The `CompositeFuture` waits for `Future tConResultFuture` and `Future sConResultFuture` to complete successfully or not and than call its `Handler`. Now both asynchronous results are finished and you can call their results.

You and the nice thing, both asynchronous calls are done concurrently.